# Angular 4 app in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, angular, firebase, webview

so far i've created an android webview in Android Studio which points to a firebase hosting website.

​If i load google.com the webview is working.
If i open the firebase url in google chrome the angular app is working. But when i open the Angular App url in android webview it's not working.

​Thank you very much!!
Kind Regards

-- MainActivity

```
package com.example.z.webview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("​​​​​**http://www.google.com**"); **​// path to angular app​**

    }
}
```

-- AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.z.webview">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

-- activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.z.webview.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"></WebView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?